# Java Sub Class List Can NOT be Returned As Super Class List

Tags: java, inheritance

It is about inheritance.
Now I have two classes,

1. Super Class

   ```
   public class TestSuper {}
   ```
2. Sub Class

   ```
   public class TestSub extends TestSuper{

       private TestSub testSub;
       private List<TestSub> testSubList;

       public TestSuper getTestStub(){
           return testSub;
       }

       public List<TestSuper> getTestStubList() {
           //compile error here
           return testSubList;
       }
   }
   ```

I can NOT return `testSubList`, the error is `Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<TestSub> to List<TestSuper>`. But why can I return `testSub`?

Comment: `List<TestSub>` is not a subtype of `List<TestSuper>` so naturally you cannot return it. If you have a "classroom for kids" and return it from a method which returns a "classroom", then you could add an adult to the classroom.

Comment: This question is not about inheritance it is about Generics..

Comment: You could try using List<? extends TestSuper> this should allow your cast to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot explicitly cast from **List< A >** to **List< B >**. You must iterate and cast each element individually.

```
public List<B> castAList(List<A> aList){

    List<B> bList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(A a : aList){
       bList.add((B) a);
    }

    return bList;
}
```

Another solution is to explicitly declare the inheritance within the generics by taking advantage of the wildcard **?**

```
List<? extends SuperClass> superList
```

Comment: The second workaround is fine